# Converting hexadecimal to MIPs instruction

Tags: binary, hex, mips

Suppose the opcode of an MIPS instruction is 0 in decimal, the funct is 100001 in binary, and the rest of the machine code is cc560 in hexadecimal (from high-order bit to low-order bit). What is the instruction? When showing the registers, use names (e.g. $t0, $s2) instead of indices (e.g $8, $17).

Comment: The MIPS instruction is `addu`.

Comment: show the entire MIPS instruction hex...